# Have an Entertainment Mission that is not complete

Tags: jurassic-world-evolution

I'm on Isla Pena, and when I look at the Reputation tab, it has "Entertainment Unlocks Complete" with a check mark. However, if I flip that tab over, I see "Mission: The Star Attraction" is still listed as New. If I go to the Fossils Research tab, the Kentrosaurus is still locked saying "Isla Pena Ent. Mission Incomplete".

I do remember that mission popping up, but I don't remember what happened with it. Evidently it didn't complete. Is there any way to start that mission again, or am I stuck having to restart the island again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each island, there is one "main" mission per faction type. When that big mission first appears, it allows you to Pass on it for now. If you do that, or fail the mission, you can restart it at any time by going to Island Management (the first tab of the management screens). In the lower right hand corner, there is a Missions window. If you select that, you can choose between the 3 types, and if you haven't completed it, but have unlocked it, you can choose to start it at any time.